# How to center onsen ui button bar on a page

Tags: html, css, onsen-ui

I am trying to place the button bar in the center of the page.
I am trying with

> text-align:center

But the expected result is not coming.

Stuck here.some help will be much appreciated.Here is the code.

```
                <div class="button-bar" style="width:300px;" style="text-align:center">
                    <div class="button-bar__item" style="text-align:center">
                        <button class="button-bar__button">Prev</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button-bar__item" style="text-align:center">
                        <button class="button-bar__button">Hint</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button-bar__item" style="text-align:center">
                        <button class="button-bar__button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You have to correct `style` attribute that could only be declared once: `style="width:300px; text-align:center;"` and add `display: inline-block` to child elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/9n0czw7s/1/

You can only center inline(-block) elements with `text-align: center`. However, divs are by default block elements so they are not subject to the text-align rule. You can override the default in CSS by using `display: inline-block;` like so:

```
.button-bar {
    text-align: center;
}

.button-bar > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can center the div

http://jsfiddle.net/9n0czw7s/

You should put *margin left and right* to *auto*

```
.button-bar {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display:inline-block to the "button-bar__item" and edit this line here:

```
<div class="button-bar" style="width:300px;" style="text-align:center">
```

to this one here:

```
<div class="button-bar" style="text-align:center">
```

and finally add

```
.button-bar{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto
 }
```

That should do it.